# View is not displayed when a variable is changed SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

i'm trying to change my View when a Variable is changed, but all i got is an empty view.

```
  var body: some View {
  
            if syncViewModel._order.status == 1369 {
                orderConfirmed
            }
            if syncViewModel._order.status == 5570 {
            orderOnTheWay
            }
    }
```

I want to change the view based on the status id. Status id is succesfully changed to " 5570 " ( I checked ), but the view is going to be empty. orderConfirmed and orderOnTheWay contains only some Text . What can be the issue ?

Comment: Is `_order` a struct and @Published`?

Comment: @aheze is in my ViewModel and is Published, yes.

Comment: always provide the fallout view, your case is when your status not 5570 or 1369; and use switch case is easier to debug

Answer (score 0):

I may be incorrect here but it looks like you're just accessing a value of a published object, not binding your UI to the published object itself. So (if I'm right) the UI is not actually subscribing to object and therefore not being told when it changes.

Unfortunately my SwiftUi experience is still pretty new so I can't offer a suggestion as to how to fix it, but I'd guess you need to find a way to get the UI to watch the published object for changes.

A quick search of the interwebs surfaced https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-observedobject-to-manage-state-from-external-objects which looks like it might be very similar to what you are trying to do.